# How to Solve Datatype issue in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have one collection view with  textbox in each cell.I am fetching values from a nsmutable dictionary and set text box text in the cell using following codes.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionviewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *datadictionary = [_currencyDictionary objectForKey:_currencyNameDetails[_flag]];
    cell.currenyRate.text = [datadictionary objectForKey:_currencyRateValueDetails[row]];
    return cell;

}
```

In this situation my application is crashed show error ....

Terminating app due to uncaught exception '

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I find the reason for that one using below mentioned method.[datadictionary objectForKey:_currencyRateValueDetails[row]] object is is in nsnumber format .

```
if([[datadictionary objectForKey:_currencyRateValueDetails[row]] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"nsnumber......");
    }
    else{NSLog(@"nsstring......");
}
```

so rewrite my code to

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     CollectionviewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *datadictionary = [_currencyDictionary objectForKey:_currencyNameDetails[_flag]];
    NSNumber *Value =[[NSNumber alloc]init];
    Value = [currenymap objectForKey:_currencyRateValueDetails[row]];
    NSString *myString = [Value stringValue];
    cell.currenyRate.text = myString;
    return cell;


}
```

This time application crash again show the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>   reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString stringValue]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can try to use NSString *myStringWithNumbers = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[currenymap objectForKey:_currencyRateValueDetails[row]]];

Comment: @user2071152 thank you its working.If you put it your comment as answer i will set as correct answer.

Comment: @user2071152 i need one more help to convert NSString to NSNumber like this method

Comment: For strings starting with integers, e.g., @"123", etc., use -[NSString integerValue]. (NSInteger number=[string integerValue];). You can also use NSNumberFormatter as  NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString:stringNum];
[f release];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
NSString *myStringWithNumbers = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[currenymap objectForKey:_currencyRateValueDetails[row]]];
```

Hope this helps.